# SQL Server : storing last 5 dates

Tags: sql-server, pseudocode

Looking for advice on how I go about writing this code.

I have a table of unique values being ported over from one system to another. And I want to store a record of say the last 5 dates of when the record was brought over.

So for example, Item A is refreshed from System X to System Y on the 1st October 2017, I want to store this date in the table. Then over the next month, it is brought over another 4 times, so I want these date values also written into that table.

Now that the last 5 dates have been written, I need some way of maintaining the code so that any new dates that come in will overwrite the table data, so that we will always have at most the last 5 update dates in this table.

Example Data;
The date columns represent the last 5 updates that have occured for each property row.

```
Property ID's, Date 1,   Date 2,   Date 3,  Date 4,   Date 5
1              01/07/17, 01/08/17 01/10/17 05/10/17 10/10/17
2              01/01/17 01/03/17 01/06/17 05/10/17 10/10/17
3              01/02/17 05/02/17 01/10/17 05/10/17 10/10/17
4              01/03/17 01/08/17 01/10/17
```

If property 4 has an update from system X, date 4 gets populated.
If property 3 has an update from system x, Dates 2 to 5 would move left one position and date 5 would get populated with the latest date.

Would this be the best way of recording last 5 updates.

Alternatively, i could just write each property id and date of update into a table and have some sort of cleaning routine of only keeping 5 entries per property.

Apologies if I'm being vague.

Comment: just 5 records in total, or 5 records in the group? Let's say 5 records for System X,Y; 5 records for System X,Z; 5 records for A,B and so on? Anyway the good way of asking questions here is to provide sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use table like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ChangeDates (
    PropertyID int,
    DateChanged date
)
```

And just write data in it. Then create view like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Top5ChangeDates 
AS
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  PropertyID,
            DateChanged,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyID ORDER BY DateChanged DESC) as rn
    FROM dbo.ChangeDates
)

SELECT  PropertyID,
        DateChanged
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5
GO
```

Or use after insert TRIGGER instead of view, to clear data.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I think i was over complicating things

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the most recent 5 records then it seems like `MERGE`, allowing simultaneous `INSERT` and `DELETE` activity may be the way to go.

This script demonstrates a `MERGE` that keeps the most recent 5 rows per `ID` value:

```
create table #History (ID int not null, OccurredAt datetime2(7) not null)
go
declare @current table (ID int not null)
insert into @current (ID) values (1),(3)

;With Keeps as (
    select
        *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OccurredAt desc) as rn
    from #History
    where ID in (select ID from @current)
)
merge into #History t
using (select ID,SYSDATETIME() from @current
        union all
      select ID,OccurredAt from Keeps where rn between 1 and 4) s(ID,OccurredAt)
on
    t.ID = s.ID and
    t.OccurredAt = s.OccurredAt
when not matched then insert (ID,OccurredAt) values (s.ID,s.OccurredAt)
when not matched by source and t.ID in (select ID from @current) then delete;

waitfor delay '00:00:01'
go 30
select * from #History
```

Hopefully you can see how the CTE finds the "other" rows that should be preserved and how the two `not matched` clauses then handle the `INSERT` and `DELETE` activities.